# Why is Phonegap SMS function executing both, success and error

Tags: cordova, sms

I am using an SMS send function in my phonegap app.

```
send(number, message, intent, success, error)
```

The app is able to send the SMSes; the issue is that both, success and error execute (I know this because I put an alert in both, success and error). I need to find the status of the SMSes I've sent. Please help me out.
Thanks!

Extra Info: Here are some related imports

*index.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sms.js"></script>
```

*config.xml*

```
<gap:plugin name="tr.bel.mamak.sms_plagin" version="0.1.0" />
```

Here is some relevant code

```
sendSms : function(sName, tName, pName, pNum, homework) {
    //SMS Message
    var message = "Testing SMS by sending it to " + pName;

    var intent = "";
    var success = alert("Success!");
    var error = alert('Message Failed');
    sms.send(pNum, message, intent, success , error);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is to add the following lines to your config.xml:

`<gap:plugin name="com.cordova.plugins.sms"/>`

You can find the plugin documentation to send SMS here: https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin

Details of the phonegap build plugin:
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1999

Comment: Building the app locally also solved this issue. But still, thanks for uploading it on build.phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin

```
 sendSms: function() {
    alert('click');
    var number = document.getElementById('numberTxt').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('messageTxt').value;
    alert(number);
    alert(message);
    var intent = 'INTENT'; //leave empty for sending sms using default intent
    var success = function () { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
    var error = function (e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
    sms.send(number, message, intent, success, error);
}
```

Comment: My code uses the same function as the one you've posted above. But when I try to add this line to config.xml
`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.plugin.sms" />`
and build the app on build.phonegap.com. I get this error
_plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.plugin.sms_

Comment: I tried to put success and error in functions as shown in your post. But when my message sending failed, I didn't get an error message. I'm sending the intent as empty (I want the SMSes to be sent in the background).

Comment: This is a different plugin. You just can't use a method from one plugin to another. I used this plugin locally, and faced no issue till now. Don't know how to use with phonegap build.

Comment: @MJB, you should consider using the new repository https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin (former https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin), I am the new maintainer and will be happy to help you.

Comment: @AtanuCSE I was using the same plugin but to build on phonegap.build we need to add the link for the plugin (which is what I am missing). I tried to add the line `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.plugin.sms.Sms" />`
But I'm still getting the unsupported plugin error. Thanks though.

Comment: @icl1c I even tried to implement the plugin from the new repository but Im still getting the unsupported plugin error when I add this line to config.xml `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.plugin.sms.Sms" />`. What should I add in config.xml to make phonegap.build add support for this new plugin in my app. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried adding the line (to config.xml) `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.plugin.sms" />` but still got plugin unsupported error.

Comment: @MJB, the new plugin hasn't been submitted to phonegap build yet. I will submit it by this weekend.

Comment: @icl1c Oh. Ok thanks. So this line (org.apache.cordova.plugin.sms) will work then right?

Comment: @MJB, we encountered some issues when we tried to submit it, we are working on it. You can follow up there https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/issues/2

Comment: @MJB you should add ```<gap:plugin name="com.cordova.plugins.sms" version="0.1.1" />```